# Different colours for rings of a buffer

Tags: qgis, symbology, buffer

I am looking for a way to create a multi distance buffer and have each buffer a different colour. For example, a buffer around a point has 5 rings. I would like to have each ring a different colour fill.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Multi-Ring Buffer tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multi-ring-buffer-constant-distance) that will create a polygon layer with three attributes:

1. **OBJECTID:** The original ID of the point
2. **RingId:** a sequence of numbers from 1 to the amount of buffers you perform in each point.
3. **distance:** the distance from the original point to the buffer.

Running this tool from 2 points, 5 buffers and a spacing of 5 meters will generate the buffers with the following attributes:

[image]

If you want to use always the same colors for each distance you can symbolize using either ringId or distance.

In case you want a unique color for each buffer you can use a combination of two fields: OBJECTID and one of the other two. Like this:

[image]